# Jquery .animate() works but in firefox the layers moved down as a result of the animation won't regain their former state after animation finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Using this for basically enlarging an image on hover
and having it go back to its former size on hover out.
This works in all browsers, but in firefox the layers
that got moved down as a result of the image enlarging
won't go back to their original position and there then
appers a big gap which equals to the height (380) that
the image was resized to.  Using 1.6.4

```
$(".PartThumbnail").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);
    $(this).animate({
        height : 380,
        width : 380,
    }, "fast");
}, function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 0);
    $(this).animate({
        height : "45",
        width : "45",
    }, "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, change:

```
height: "380px",
width: "380px",
```

Notice you omitted " " around CSS value and pixel designation.

Do the same for:

```
height: "45px",
width: "45px",
```

See if that works.

Also, post your HTML/CSS/JavaScript with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can better help you.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Will try to get the fiddle up shortly. Putting px after width/height values and quotes around values in css() did not help.